# What are the coordinates on my rectangle of the closest point to a polygon in R?

Tags: r, distance, spatial-query, sp, rgeos

I have a non-overlapping extent rectangle and a sample lake polygon. I can measure the distance from the rectangle to the polygon but I want to know which point on the rectangle is the closest to the polygon (i.e. the coordinates of that closest point on the rectangle).

```
library("raster")
library("rgeos")

# extent rectangle
rect <- as(extent(956328.8, 1036613, 825238.9, 936911.5), "SpatialPolygons")

# lake polygon
x <- c(1199999, 1080000, 1093067, 1090190, 1087977, 1070419, 1180419)
y <- c(957803.6,937803.6, 894366.9, 872153.9, 853703.0, 825353.6, 805353.6)
poly.lake <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(data.frame(x,y))), ID = 1)))

# measure distance
rect.dist <- gDistance(rect, poly.lake)

# get coordinates of closest point...?
```

Comment: What is the `extent` function? I guess from `raster`? I also see that function in `gazetools`...

Comment: Also, by point "on" the rectangle, are you restricting to the vertices, or to any point along the border?

Comment: And in general, `rect` consists of more than one polygon?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I'm interested in any point on the rectangle, not just the vertices.

Comment: that's substantially more difficult... I suspect any approach I offer would be quite slow. there may be a routine doing this in C somewhere...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3700983/3576984

Comment: Perhaps consider using [postgis](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the *vertices* from a **polygon** are the closest points from another **polygon** you can use the **Answer 1** example. However, sometimes may occur that a *line segment* from one **polygon** is the closest part of a **polygon** from another **polygon**. In that case, you can use the **Answer 2** example. It compares all the *vertices* from one polygon against all possible *line segments* from the other **polygon** and viceversa. It takes the minimum distance and positions using the function `dist2Line` from the `R` package `geosphere`.

```
# Load libraries ----------------------------------------------------------

# Libraries for GIS
library('raster')
library('rgeos')
library('geosphere')

# Libraries for plots
library('latticeExtra')
library('RColorBrewer')

# Load data ---------------------------------------------------------------

# Extent rectangle
rect <- as(extent(956328.8, 1036613, 825238.9, 936911.5), "SpatialPolygons")

# Lake polygon
x <- c(1199999, 1080000, 1093067, 1090190, 1087977, 1070419, 1180419)
y <- c(957803.6,937803.6, 894366.9, 872153.9, 853703.0, 825353.6, 805353.6)
poly.lake <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(data.frame(x,y))), ID = 1)))
```

#### Answer 1

**This example work only for polygon vertices**

```
# Get coordinates from polygons -------------------------------------------

lake.points <- SpatialPoints(coords = poly.lake@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)
rect.points <- SpatialPoints(coords = rect@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)

# Measure distances between SpatialPoints objects
rect.dist <- gDistance(rect.points, lake.points, byid = TRUE)

# Minimum distance
minDist <- rect.dist[which(rect.dist == min(rect.dist))]

# Coordinates of min distance 
mCoord <- as.data.frame(which(rect.dist == minDist, arr.ind=TRUE))

# Get coordinates of closest points ---------------------------------------

# The points from lake polygons are the rows in the "rect.dist" matrix
# The points from rect polygons are the columns in the "rect.dist" matrix

# Coordinates of the closest point from poly.lake 
coordsClosestPointPolyLake <- coordinates(lake.points[mCoord$row,])

# Coordinates of the closest point from poly.rect 
coordsClosestPointPolyRect <- coordinates(rect.points[mCoord$col,])

# Plot of polygons and closest points
plot(rect, xlim = c(extent(rect)[1], extent(poly.lake)[2]), ylim = extent(poly.lake)[3:4], col = "red")
plot(poly.lake, col = "cyan", add = TRUE)
plot(lake.points[mCoord$row,], col = "blue", pch = 10, cex = 2, add = TRUE)
plot(rect.points[mCoord$col,], col = "darkred", pch = 10, cex = 2, add = TRUE)
```

[image: answer1]

#### Answer 2

**This example work for vertices and also when some line segment from a polygon is closer (to the other polygon) than their vertices**

```
# Define projection (this projection is an example, I don't know what projection the original data apply to)
projExample <- "+proj=utm +zone=50 +north +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

# Get coordinates of each polygon and transform to SpatialPoints object
lake.points <- SpatialPoints(coords = poly.lake@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords, proj4string = CRS(projExample))
rect.points <- SpatialPoints(coords = rect@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords, proj4string = CRS(projExample))

# Make SpatialLinesDataFrame objects --------------------------------------

# Make SpatialLines objects - line segments - from points (SpatialPoints objects) 

# Lake
lake.lines <- list()

for(i in 1:(length(lake.points) - 1)) {

  lake.lines[[i]] <- Lines(slinelist = Line(coords = coordinates(lake.points[c(i, i + 1)])), ID = paste(i))

  }

lake.lines <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl = SpatialLines(lake.lines, proj4string = CRS(projExample)), data = data.frame("ID" = paste(1:(length(lake.points) - 1))), match.ID = TRUE)

# Rect
rect.lines <- list()

for(i in 1:(length(rect.points) - 1)) {

  rect.lines[[i]] <- Lines(slinelist = Line(coords = coordinates(rect.points[c(i, i + 1)])), ID = paste(i))

  }

rect.lines <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(sl = SpatialLines(rect.lines, proj4string = CRS(projExample)), data = data.frame("ID" = paste(1:(length(rect.points) - 1))), match.ID = TRUE)

# Plots -------------------------------------------------------------------

# Plot line segments 

# (optional: only a margin from spatial objects in the plot)
xOffset <- 30000
yOffset <- 30000

# Main plot
plotRectLines <- spplot(rect.lines, zcol = "ID", lwd = 2, col.regions = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(4, "Dark2"), xlim = c(extent(rect)[1] - xOffset, extent(poly.lake)[2] + xOffset), ylim = c(extent(poly.lake)[3] - yOffset, extent(poly.lake)[4] + yOffset), colorkey = FALSE)

# Spatial layers to add to the plot
layerLakeLines <- layer(sp.lines(lake.lines, zcol = "ID", lwd = 2, col = brewer.pal(7, "Accent")))
layerRectLinesLabels <- layer(sp.text(coordinates(getSpatialLinesMidPoints(rect.lines)), txt = as.character(rect.lines$ID)))
layerLakeLinesLabels <- layer(sp.text(coordinates(getSpatialLinesMidPoints(lake.lines)), txt = as.character(lake.lines$ID)))

# Run Main plot + layers
plotRectLines + layerLakeLines + layerRectLinesLabels + layerLakeLinesLabels

# Calculate distances between vertices and lines --------------------------

# First: transform coordinates to WGS84 (lon lat) when using function dist2Line
# The dist2Line function calculate the minimum distance between points and lines and also return the closest position from the line where the minimum distance was measured. 

# Distances between points from "rect" and lines from "lake"
distRect2Lake <- dist2Line(p = spTransform(rect.points, CRSobj = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")), line = spTransform(lake.lines, CRSobj = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")))

# Convert to data frame
distRect2Lake <- as.data.frame(distRect2Lake)

# Add reference category (where positions belongs to)
distRect2Lake$object <- rep("lake", nrow(distRect2Lake))

# Distances between points from "lake" and lines from "rect"
distLake2Rect <- dist2Line(p = spTransform(lake.points, CRSobj = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")), line = spTransform(rect.lines, CRSobj = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")))

# Convert to data frame
distLake2Rect <- as.data.frame(distLake2Rect)

# Add reference category (where positions belongs to)
distLake2Rect$object <- rep("rect", nrow(distLake2Rect))

# Merge data frames distances
mergeDistances <- as.data.frame(rbind(distRect2Lake, distLake2Rect))

# Minimum distances -------------------------------------------------------

# Query minimum distances from mergeDistances data frame
minDistRows <- which(mergeDistances$distance == min(mergeDistances$distance))

# Extract closest points from mergeDistances data frame
closestPoints <- mergeDistances[minDistRows,]

# Transform closest points to SpatialPointsDataFrame object
closestPointsSPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = closestPoints[,2:3], data = closestPoints[,-c(2:3)], proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# Project to original projection (UTM Zone 50N)
# Remember: this projection is arbitrary.
closestPointsSPDF <- spTransform(x = closestPointsSPDF, CRSobj = CRS(projExample))

# ---> Here is the answer to this question <---
# ---> coordinates of the closest points <---
(coordinates(closestPointsSPDF))

# Final plot --------------------------------------------------------------

# Make layers from closest points
layerClosestPointFromRect <- layer(sp.points(obj = closestPointsSPDF[closestPointsSPDF$object == "rect", ], pch = 10, cex = 2, col = "red", lwd = 2))
layerClosestPointFromLake <- layer(sp.points(obj = closestPointsSPDF[closestPointsSPDF$object == "lake", ], pch = 10, cex = 2, col = "blue", lwd = 2))

# Plot results
plotRectLines + layerLakeLines + layerRectLinesLabels + layerLakeLinesLabels + layerClosestPointFromRect + layerClosestPointFromLake
```

[image]

**Note:** every line segment of the polygon is labeled and the closest point from the **rect** and **lake** polygons in red and blue respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The is already implemented in the GEOS library (`GEOSNearestPoints_r`) and is now wrapped in the `rgeos` package (>= 0.3-21), see `gNearestPoints`:

```
gDistance(rect, poly.lake)
# [1] 33806
gNearestPoints(rect, poly.lake)
# class       : SpatialPoints 
# features    : 2 
# extent      : 1036613, 1070419, 825354, 825354  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
coordinates(gNearestPoints(rect, poly.lake))
#         x      y
# 1 1036613 825354
# 2 1070419 825354

plot(gUnion(rect, poly.lake))
plot(gNearestPoints(rect, poly.lake), add=TRUE, col="red", pch=4)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the coordinates, then use nearest neighbor between the points to find the closest one. This only works if you are restricting to vertices, as asked above.

```
library(broom)
library(FNN)
lake.coords <- tidy(poly.lake)[c("long", "lat")]
rect.coords <- tidy(rect)[c("long", "lat")]
nn <- get.knnx(lake.coords, rect.coords, k=1)
rect.coords[which.min(nn$nn.dist),]
```